# running "source ./file.sh" in ubuntu mate during start up

Tags: shell, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, boot

I am trying to run a shell script during boot up in Ubuntu mate(in a raspberry pi). I am not sure where to add this line "source ./file.sh". Thank you in advance.

Comment: try adding script either in init folder in /etc or in bashrc file in home folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the script code to ~/.bashrc to make it effective for a particular user or to /etc/profile to make it global.